# Google Analytics Management .Net API: Custom variable names

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics

I' porting an application from using an older version of Google Analytics Management API to the new one: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtProfileGuide

How do I get the names of the custom variables that's used for a profile?

With the previous API I could write:

```
        List<GACustomVar> result = new List<GACustomVar>();

        AccountEntry entry = _FindEntryByProfileId(profileId);

        if (entry != null)
        {
            foreach (CustomVariable variable in entry.CustomVariables)
            {
                result.Add(new GACustomVar()
                {
                    Index = int.Parse(variable.Index),
                    Name = variable.Name
                });
            }
        }

        return result;
```

But there's nothing similar in:

```
_service.Management.Accounts.List().Fetch().Items[0].
```